# How to solve "The command could not be located because '/bin:/usr/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable" error?

Tags: command-line, bash, permissions, directory, environment-variables

I've installed Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS and installed Anaconda3, but I had to uninstall Anaconda3 since some problem occurred. I removed it using this command as root and from the `/home/user` directory:

```
# rm -f anaconda3
```

After this I got this problem below:

```
$ sudo -s
# ls
Command 'ls' is available in the following places
 * /bin/ls
 * /usr/bin/ls
The command could not be located because '/bin:/usr/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.
ls: command not found
```

Here are the last few lines of my `.bashrc`:

```
# >>> conda initialize >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$('/home/thilipkumar/anaconda3/bin/conda' 'shell.bash' 'hook' 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/home/thilipkumar/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/home/thilipkumar/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
    else
        export PATH="/home/thilipkumar/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda initialize <<<
```

And here are the outputs of `echo path` for the normal user and root:

```
~$ echo $PATH
/home/thilipkumar/anaconda3/condabin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
~$ sudo -s
/home/thilipkumar# echo $PATH
/root/anaconda3/
```

Can anyone suggest me what to do next?

Comment: @JB.Thilipkumar Could you, please, pick an [accepted answer](https://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer) ?

Answer (score 5):

Check the `/root/.profile` and `/root/.bashrc` files of the root user to correct where the path is wrongly set.

You also could revert these files to default by copying the respective files in `/etc/skel` over to `/root`.

Comment: Any suggestions on how to do this if cp is also unavailable? EDIT: for anyone else in my situation, the help text tells the you the location and you can do it directly (for instance by calling `$/bin/ls` instead of `$ls`. Apologies for the noobery!

Answer (score -1):

Please replace the file path by using:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin:/bin
```

This command replaces the path to original permanently. Here is an example:

```
/$ nano .bashrc
Command 'nano' is available in the following places
 * /bin/nano
 * /usr/bin/nano
The command could not be located because '/usr/bin:/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.
nano: command not found
/$ export PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin:/bin
/$ ls
backups  bin  boot  cdrom  dev  etc  home  lib  lib32  lib64  libx32  lost+found
madhu  media  mnt  opt  proc  root  run  sbin  snap  srv  swapfile  sys
tmp  usr  var
```